# How to set many variables with gets

Tags: ruby

I would love to set three variables `a`, `b` and `c` from a single `gets` line. For example, user entering a line of space-delimited numbers `"1 2.2 -3.14"` would set `a` to `1`, `b` to `2.2` and `c` to `-3.14` respectively. I achieve this like so:

```
input = gets.strip.split
a,b,c = input[0].to_f,input[1].to_f,input[2].to_f
```

Is there a more elegant way to assign array entries to a range of variables? Perhaps something with a splat and a cycle?

```
input.each {|entry| *(a..z) = entry }
```

Comment: `a` would be set to 1.0 (a `Float`), rather than 1 (a `Fixnum`). Is that ok?

Comment: Yes, the extra precision will not hurt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a,b,c = "1 2.2 -3.14".split.map(&:to_f)
# => [1.0, 2.2, -3.14]
b
# => 2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "scan may be 1 useful if 2.2 the string may contain -3.14 other stuff"

arr = []
str.scan(/-?\d*(?:\d|\.\d|\d\.)\d*/) { |s| arr << s.to_f }
arr #=> [1.0, 2.2, -3.14]
```

The regex extracts the embedded numbers that have zero or one decimal points.

Considering that you are using `gets` to obtain `str`, I've chosen to use `arr =` rather than `a,b,c =` so I can make sure the correct number of floats have been returned:

```
if arr.size == 3
  a,b,c = arr
else
  <raise exception>
end
```

With v1.9+ you could save a line (just saying, not advocating) by using [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
arr = [].tap { |a| str.scan(/-?\d*(?:\d|\.\d|\d\.)\d*/) { |s| a << s.to_f } }
```